# A movie “...” or THE movie “...”

Tags: definite-articles

During my English class I was giving a speech about my favorite listening practices in English and said, “I’ve recently watched the American movie “The Shawshank Redemption” and...”
At that point the teacher stopped me and said: “It should be A, not THE”. When I asked why, her explanation came down to the fact that she first heard of the movie, therefore it was “unpopular” and asked for the indefinite article.

Then I did my research and found this:

“If the noun denotes a well-known person or work of art, the definite article is generally used.
Pushkin, the great Russian poet, died in 1837.
Hamlet, the immortal tragedy by Shakespeare, was written in the first years of the 17th century.
But if the person or the work of art is not widely known the indefinite article is used.”

Can someone explain to me what should the aforementioned “popularity” of a work of art base on? Is it, in general, about being classical or popular?
[To my judgement, “The Shawshank Redemption” is a well-known movie]. 
Or does it depend of the syntactic structure of a sentence?

Comment: That explanation is wrong. As an article, *the* is used when referring to something *specific*, not something *popular*. What your teacher was talking about was using *the* as an *honorific* for someone (or something) where you would not normally use an article at all: *the (great) Winston Churchill*. (And if they are not popular, you don't use the indefinite article.) Also, *popularity* has nothing necessarily to do with whether or not *you've* heard of something (although it makes it more likely).

Comment: The issue is whether the person or work is _well-known_ rather than _popular_. We would say "The notorious serial killer, Jack the Ripper", but "a convicted murderer called Jack X".

Comment: For one thing, it can never be *a* -- if anything, it would be *an*.

Comment: That said, **recognition** is far less relevant here and the teacher is digressing from the main point. Even so, it would sometimes sound rather denigrating to use the indefinite article -- it is preferred when you seem to imply "you know, the kind of one that no one has ever heard of." In summary, the definite article is correct here.

Comment: @JasonBassford There are also other aspects. See also my comment above.

Comment: Perhaps I'm basically repeating the comments of others. But I would say that if you say "the movie Shawshank Redemption," you suggest that you think the reader is familiar with the title. If you say "a movie called Shawshank Redemption," you suggest that you do not take this for granted. This very slight difference in meaning is the only important difference. Both are grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of *a/an* or *the* depends soley on whether the noun phrase following is [a restrictive or non-restrictive appositive](http://www.sjsu.edu/writingcenter/docs/handouts/Appositives.pdf), that is, whether or not it is necessary to the basic meaning of the sentence. There are also implications for punctuation, which in spoken English usually corresponds to a slight pause and change of pitch (with comma) or just plowing ahead (no comma).

> Later [*the Viennese psychoanalyst Sigmund Freud*](https://books.google.de/books?id=BBVAAQAAIAAJ&q=%22the+Viennese+psychoanalyst+Sigmund%22&dq=%22the+Viennese+psychoanalyst+Sigmund%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT_rrf9KjdAhXilIsKHeWjD9kQ6AEIRjAF) adapted the myth and deduced from it one basic thought of psychoanalytic theory, namely, the incestuous longing of the little boy for his mother and, at the same time, his hatred of his father. — *Classical and Modern Literature*, vol. 15, 1994. 346.
>
> But it was [*a Viennese psychoanalyst, Sigmund Freud,*](https://www.scribd.com/document/216512504/Dream-Warnings-of-Cancer-Heart-Disease-and-Other-Illnesses-May-Save-Your-Life) who managed to revive them [dreams and dream research]… — Terry Gillis, *Dream Warnings of Cancer*, 2014.

In the first sentence, identical in structure to your example, *the Viennese psychoanalyst Sigmund Freud* is really a single noun phrase. Freud’s name restricts *psychoanalyst* to a specific person, thus the definite article is used.

In the second, Freud’s name is nonrestrictive, the name gives supplemental information, but it is not necessary to the basic meaning of the sentence.

So you have the choice:

> the American movie *The Shawshank Redemption* (restrictive, no comma)

or

> an American movie, *The Shawshank Redemption,* (nonrestrictive, with comma or commas)

Comment: I think that the question was whether to say "an" or "the," not which punctuation to use.

Comment: You can't have one without the other.

Answer (score -8):

The American movie implies there is only one American movie, so a American movie is correct. Also, if you want to speak English (as opposed to American pigeon English)use the word "FILM" not "MOVIE" movie is a horrible Americanism.

Comment: If you're going to be snide, please spell correctly: pidjin.

Comment: Nice try. "A American" is not English.  In English, we write "an American". Perhaps the pigeons know better.

Comment: @KarlG - I second your sentiment... but it's actually spelt [pidgin](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pidgin?s=ts) ;)

Comment: Damn! I know I should have looked it up! _pidjin_ is how it's spelled in German.